# Time complexity of a Divide and Conquer

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, master-theorem

I have Master theorem for finding complexities but 
the problem is 
Master theorem says

For a recurrence of form

```
T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n) where a >= 1 and b > 1
```

There are following three cases:
 /******************logba means log of a with b as base **************/

1. `If f(n) = Θ(n^c) where c < Logba then T(n) = Θ(nLogba)`
2. `If f(n) = Θ(n^c) where c = Logba then T(n) = Θ(ncLog n)`
3. `If f(n) = Θ(n^c) where c > Logba then T(n) = Θ(f(n))`

Now for My Problem

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + n^2
```

My Solution `c = 2` and `logba = log` of `2` with `1` as `base = infinity`
So in which case it falls and what is the complexity

Comment: This sounds like a theoretical CS question - there's a separate stackexchange.com site for that.

Comment: Here -> http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case `b=2` and `a=1` so `Log_b(a)` is `log of 1 in base 2` and not `log of 2 in base 1`.

See:

```
T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n)
T(n) =  T(n/2) + n^2
```

As `Log_b(a) = Log_2(1) = 0`, you fall in case **3**.

Comment: No it is ------ log of 2 base 1

Comment: @iankit3 I quote you: `logba means log of a with b as base`, so if `b=2` the base is `2` not `1`

Comment: sorry , it was a blunder ! Thanks for making that right - fjardon